# Connecting to multiple servers from a single client

Tags: c++, tcp

I have 10.000 small device and those have one server port(waiting connection). I want to connect all devices at the same time with one Server(PC). Can I open port for each Device? Is it possible for Windows ? thnx

Comment: If each device has "server" port awaiting a connection and you're trying to connect to the device from another machine, isn't the PC a client?

Comment: [500,000 connections are possible](http://urbanairship.com/blog/2010/09/29/linux-kernel-tuning-for-c500k/)

Comment: BigMike->TCP Connection is needed. 
André Caron->Our Server (PC) will have 10.000 client-ports.
J.F. Sebastian-> Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Read section 4.8 on [this page](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/advanced.html). It looks like the answer is yes, in principle, but you need to do asynchronous IO, because you can't run 10000 threads on Windows at the same time.

Comment: *Not true*. It certainly possible to run 10000 threads on Windows, see [Thousands of Threads and Blocking I/O, slide 25](http://www.mailinator.com/tymaPaulMultithreaded.pdf) and [Does Windows have a limit of 2000 threads per process?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/29/444912.aspx) but you shouldn't do it only because you can.

Comment: Thanks Jan de Vaan and J.F. Sebastian. I really want use Synchronous IO. Because Every packet and time is important. I'll put all message to database directly.I mean Thread can run in different processes. If I can run 8 process and I can divede to work(like each process 1250 threads). What do you think? I know 10.000 threads isn't recomended but is it also problem with PC? Or any offers.

Comment: Quoting from the 2nd link J.F. supplied: 'The "one thread per client" model is well-known not to scale beyond a dozen clients or so.'.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you used a reasonably efficient polling strategy (e.g. I/O completion ports, if you're using Windows) and keep the kernel socket buffers fairly small, it's possible in principle.  However, if reliability is not a large concern, and you can control both ends of the protocol (i.e., you're designing the devices), UDP would be far more efficient - with UDP you could read from all devices using a single socket.

If TCP is a requirement, you'll have an absolute limit of 60,000 connections from a single interface because TCP port numbers are only 16 bits, i.e., 64k possible values.  Eventually you'll run out of local port numbers, unless you do something exotic like giving your network interface more than one IP address.

Comment: [The 64k Connection Myth](http://urbanairship.com/blog/2010/09/29/linux-kernel-tuning-for-c500k/#the_64k_connection_myth).

Answer (score 0):

The way to actually do this is to have the devices listen on a specific multicast group. This way you can just broadcast a packet and the machines listening to that group will (most likely) receive the packet.

This also give many benefits of dividing things into groups using multicast addresses.

Note that there is a possibility of lost packets - so I suggest sequence numbering/recovery method if every single message is important.